# Debugging Amazon SQS consumers

Tags: amazon-sqs

I'm working with a  PHP frontend which connects to a distributed back end, using Amazon SQS and a variety of message types and message consumers. I'm trying to come up with a way to safely debug those consumers, as we don't want message handlers with new, untested code consuming end-user messages, risking the messages being lost or incorrectly processed.

The actual message queue names are hardcoded as PHP constants in a class, so my first tactic was to create two different sets of queues, one for production and another for debugging, and to externalise the queue name constants into two different files. Depending on whether our debug condition is true or not, I wanted to include one or the other of those constant definitions and assign the constants in the included file to the class constants which currently have the names hardcoded.

This doesn't seem to work though because constants seem to act like class variables in PHP whereas I am trying to assign the values like instance variables. The next tactic was to see if there was anything on Amazon's side that would allow us to debug our message consumers transparently without adding lots of hacks to our code, but I couldn't see anything there that facilitated this. I'd love to know if anyone else has experienced (and ideally, solved this problem)

Answer (score 2):

SQS doesn't provide a way to inspect the contents of messages in the queue, or for the sender to see if any consumers are failing to process messages.

A common approach to this problem would be to set up two sets of queues as you suggest and have the producer post the same message onto both queues.  That way you can debug your code against a stream of production messages without affecting the actual production queue.

I'd recommend moving the decision of which queue to use out of your code and into config, and then deploy different config files to your development boxes vs your production boxes.   The risk is always that a development box ends up talking to production systems, so having a single consistent approach to configuring those end-points across all your code is much less risky that doing it on an ad-hoc basis each time you call out to a service.

I'd also recommend putting your production and development queues in different AWS accounts with different access credentials.  That way you can give your production account permission to publish to the development account's queue, but you can guarantee that your development systems can't read from the production queue.